# Yii - Admin Can Update Everything while Users Can Only Update Their Own Account

Tags: php, yii

I have a problem while doing this, Users perfectly can only update their own data, but unfortunately Admin cannot update everything, just update himself like any common users.
My idea is put `$id = Yii::app()->user->id;` in function aactionUpdate so like this:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $id = Yii::app()->user->id;
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['User']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id_user));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Then I think I have to put `'update'` in actionRules as an admin, like this:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('create','captcha'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('view','update'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','admin','delete', 'update'),
            //'users'=>array('admin'),
            'expression'=>'$user->getLevel()<=1',
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

But as Admin, still cannot update everything, only update himself.

Any approaches I should do? Please give me suggestions, thanks.

*PS: I don't use any users and rights extensions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, but you clearly declared at first line of your `actionUpdate()` that you always want to update the currently logged in user! What's your problem?

If you want normal users to update themselves and admin to update anyone then first line given your framework code should look like this:

```
$isAdmin = Yii::app()->user->getLevel() <=1; // or how you define admin in your case.
if (!$isAdmin)
    $id = Yii::app()->user->id;
```

Normally you define a RBAC and do the following:

```
$isAdmin = Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('admin');
```

Comment: oh yes I see, I'm sorry really a newbie in Yii. Thanks for your help

Comment: Being newbie is not a problem. Denying what you clearly stated yourself is. ;) Maybe you want to read about what the "Yii::app()->user" is, both in the [documentation about CWebUser](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser) and in the [documentation about authentication system in Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth).